# Subtitle explorer from GOM player has dissapeared

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, gom-player

I have problem with subtitle explorer in GOM player. When I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or select `Subtitle explorer` in context menu, nothing happens, though check appears next to the context menu item:
`✓ Subtitle explorer`

Could the subtitle explorer window be off-screen or something like that? I sometimes use second monitor when projecting movies. Could the explorer be stuck on that, now disconnected, monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is a bug in GOM player. After connecting my PC back to the big screen, I found the subtitle explorer there.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I didn't find any solution... I just uninstall and reinstall GOM player, and started working again.

Comment: For me, it was hanging on the other screen.